# how to define parser when using BS4 in python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaKt8dvEIPnEHWSbLYhzrxg/videos"
response = requests.get(url)
# parse html
page = str(BeautifulSoup(response.content))


def getURL(page):
    """

    :param page: html of web page (here: Python home page) 
    :return: urls in that page 
    """
    start_link = page.find("a href")
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1: end_quote]
    return url, end_quote

while True:
    url, n = getURL(page)
    page = page[n:]
    if url:
        print(url)
    else:
        break
```

I am using above code to get list of all youtube videos on webpage. If i try to do this. I get following error

```
The code that caused this warning is on line 9 of the file C:/Users/PycharmProjects/ReadCSVFile/venv/Links.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:
```

I did and started using html but some different error came .

I am using Python 3.0 . I am using IDE Pycharm.

Can someone please help me  this.

Answer (score 0):

its not error, but warning you didn't set parser which can be `'html.parser'`, `'lxml'`, `'xml'`. change it to like

```
page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

your code above actually not doing what `BeautifulSoup` do, but here the example using it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getURL(url):
    """
    :param url: url of web page
    :return: urls in that page 
    """
    response = requests.get(url)
    # parse html
    page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    link_tags = page.find_all('a')
    urls = [x.get('href') for x in link_tags]
    return urls

url = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaKt8dvEIPnEHWSbLYhzrxg/videos"
all_url = getURL(url)
print('\n'.join(all_url))
```